# How to reset SQL table-data while in transaction

Tags: c#, sql, database, transactions

Code:

**BusinessLayer**:

```
 // an array of type int with 3 values is present
 foreach(var item in list)
 {
   //Pseudocode incoming
   Query_DoSomethingWithItem(item.Identifier, myArray)
 }
```

**DAL**:

```
 DoSomethingWithItem(long id, int[] theArray)
 {
    using(var scope = new TransactionScope()
    {
       // using SqlConnection

       // fill command-parameter which makes use of a user-defined-table, which represents an array of integers.
       // Important: The underlying stored_proc WRITES to database

       conn.Open();
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       scope.Complete();
    }
 }
```

=> The problem is, it runs perfectly in the first run-through, but in the second, the UDT array-of-int is already filled with values from first execution.

How to reset the data of the UDT after first run?

I tried with TransactionScope.RequiresNew but makes no difference.

**Edit: This is what I am trying to achieve:**

Table: Objects [ObjectId, ...]

Table: Items   [ObjectId(FK), Index]

UDT: IntegerArrray

N Items can belong to 1 Object.

Answer (score 1):

We might need a bit more context to give an informed answer.  The pseudo code doesn't precisely define what you're up to.  We need more code to understand why those variables are being "re-used".  Most likely guess is that the transaction scope is interfering with the reset of the variables, or is lost on the next loop.

However, from what I can see, I can say this.  When I write software, I tend to avoid looping over sets of data in this kind of database persistence / business logic communication.

Why?  The business layer is responsible for handing off the objects / data to your data layer (repository, DAC, whatever you want to call it), and expecting some kind of response.

That response could be

- Everything turned out great
- Something went wrong

The Business Layer then will respond to these answers appropriately.  The Business Layer should not know (or care, for that matter) how the data is persisted (like looping over the data).  It simply hands the entire collection of data to the Data Layer, and let the Data Layer do the looping inside of the transaction.

This separates your concerns into:
  - The Business Layer cares about handing the data to the Data Layer, and responding to success or failure.
  - The Data Layer knows about the kind of data it will receive, and how best to persist it.

Your pseudo code could be refactored to look like this

**Business Layer:**

```
public void DoSomethingWithData(list) {
  Query_DoSomethingWithItem(list);
}
```

**DAL:**

```
 public void Query_DoSomethingWithItem(List<item> list)
 {
    using(var scope = new TransactionScope()
    {

       // using SqlConnection

       // fill command-parameter which makes use of a user-defined-table, which represents an array of integers.

       conn.Open();
       foreach(var item in list) {
            //initialise the myArray in here
            command.ExecuteNonQuery(item, myArray);
       }
       scope.Complete();
    }
 }
```

Hope this is what you were after.

Comment: Hello Mister Smith, thanks for your nice answer. It would make sense, yes. But for me, this does not "feel" right. Because inside the loop, I also have some extra if´s for checking if the item is legit. If I would move the whole logic into the DAL, it feels like I am breaking the intention of the layers...

Comment: That's a good point, and yes, the business logic should remain with the business layer.  In that case, you'd want to consider using a UnitOfWork style pattern in your business layer, or perhaps move the "if" logic into a stored procedure, if appropriate.

In the case you've described, I'd ensure the "if" rules are applied to the data in the business layer (such as "if this is true, then change this item property to X rather than Y"), and then hand it off to the DAL once all those business rules have been applied.

Comment: Looking at your code, however, it doesn't make sense to me why the DAL layer is re-using the previous variables.  Are these classes static / have static methods?  The surrounding code would definitely help to get you a really solid answer.

Comment: I have to admin I just realised that I am awful at explaining, I will re-write the question

Answer (score 0):

Why not just return what you need rather than modify an existing collection? pseudocode below:

```
// an array of type int with 3 values is present
foreach(var item in list)
{
  //Pseudocode incoming
  Query_DoSomethingWithItem(item.Identifier, myArray)
}

int[] DoSomethingWithItem(long id)
{
  var result = new List<int>();
  using(var scope = new TransactionScope()
  {
     using(var con = new SqlConnection())
     {
       using(var cmd = new sqlcommand())
       {
         con.Open();      
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();     
         // fill your list of integers.        
         scope.Complete();
      }
    }
  }
  return result.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I was unclear on the problem, I have to point out that it is WRITE, not READ access on db. On second run (second item in foreach-loop) cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() will fail, because the user-defined-table (array of integers) already has values in it.

Comment: I've always used datatables to hold the the udt data. Cant you just new up a  datatable in DoSomethingWithItem.